# Explore function of two variables for extremas at given points

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

The task is to explore the function of two variables
$$f(x,y)=-x^2(y-2)^3$$
for extremas in two points
$$A=(5,0), \qquad B=(0,5)$$
I tried to use the second derivative test, but it turns inconclusive:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -2 x (y - 2)^3, \qquad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -3 x^2 (y - 2)^2$$
so the critical points are: $\{(0,y) \mid y \in \Bbb{R}\}$ and $\{(x,2) \mid x \in \Bbb{R}\}$, that gives us that $B=(0,5)$ is critical point, but
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = -2 (y - 2)^3, \qquad \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = -6 x (y - 2)^2 \qquad \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} = -6 x^2 (y - 2)$$
and the Hessian turns to zero at this point:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \cdot \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} - (\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y})^2 = -24 x^2 (-2 + y)^4 = -24 \cdot (0)^2 \cdot (3)^4 = 0
$$
So, the question is, how can I explore **these types of functions** for extremas? (for example, for this function the test also doesn't give a conclusion: $f(x,y)=-xy^3$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As regards the point $B=(0,5)$ consider the function $f$ in a neighbourhood of the point: note that for $4<y<6$ (and for all $x$),
$$f(x,y)=-x^2(y-2)^3\leq -x^2(4-2)^3\leq 0=f(0,5).$$
What kind of extrema is $B$?

Using the same approach (or by exploring the sign of $f$), what kind of extrema are the other critical points?

Comment: If I get it right, the $B=(0,5)$ is maximum.
And for all $y > 2$ it remains maximum. But when $y$ crosses $2$ it becomes minimum?

Comment: @MrRooots Yes, and all critical points $(x,2)$ are saddle points

Comment: Thank you very much!